# Функционал Bash-а в Powershell

Tags: bash, powershell

Здравствуйте.

Появилась необходимость написать небольшой скрипт на PowerShell-е, с коим дел особо не имел. Ранее писал на Bash-е. Читал о том, что синтаксис в PowerShell очень похож на C#, но в данный момент я этого, увы, не наблюдаю. Хочу прикрутить простейшую функцию логирования, которая берёт результат выполнения последней команды. Как я это делаю в Bash:

```
Logging () {
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
            printf "OK\n"
            echo "[ OK ]     $(date '+%d.%m.%y %H:%M:%S') $*" >> $log
    else
            printf "ERROR\n"
            echo "[ ERROR ]  $(date '+%d.%m.%y %H:%M:%S') $* failed" >> $log
    fi
}
SomeOperation
Logging "Some Operation"
```

В данный момент кусок скрипта на PS выглядит так:

```
function Logging([int]$result, [string]$operation) {
    $Date=Get-Date -Format "dd.MM.yyy HH:mm:ss"
    if ($result -eq 0) {
        echo "OK"
        echo "[ OK ]     $Date $operation" >> $log
    } else {
        echo "ERROR"
        echo "[ ERROR ]  $Date $operation failed" >> $log
    }
}
$value=SomeOperation 
Logging $value "Some operation"
```

Возникшие вопросы:

Как передать функции значение, возвращаемое последней командой (в Bash за это отвечает переменная **$?**) ?

Если это невозможно, то как передать функции два параметра: возвращаемое значение другой функции + строчку текста ?

Как превратить

```
$value=SomeOperation 
Logging $value "Some operation"
```

Во что-то более приличное?

```
Logging SomeOperation "Some operation"
```

по некой причине не отрабатывает.

В Bash можно составить очень простую и удобную конструкцию вида:

```
SomeOperation && doIfTrue || doIfFalse
```

а имеется ли аналог на PS?

Добавлю ещё один вопрос: предположим, есть код вида

```
function OneFunction {
    if (Test-Path $CheckFile) {
        $result=Get-Content $CheckFile -EA SilentlyContinue
    } else {
        AnotherFunction
        $result=Get-Content $CheckFile -EA SilentlyContinue
    }
    if ($result) { return $True } else { return $False }
}
function AnotherFunction {
    cp $myFile $USBdrive
    if ($? -eq $True) { return $True } else { return $False }
}

OneFunction
```

После этого на вывод дважды подаётся возвращаемое значение: сначала от **AnotherFunction**, а потом от **OneFunction**. Как добиться того, чтобы получить лишь возвращаемое значение последней функции и ничего больше? Мне нужно логировать результат её выполнения и ничего более!

Comment: А если совершенно случайно речь идет о Windows 10, то можно вообще установить Linux Subsystem, и использовать родной bash. :)

Comment: Речь идёт о Windows Server 2008 R2, да я и не против PowerShell :)  Проблема лишь в том, что я не знаю, как реализовать то, что мне в данный момент нужно.

Answer (score 2):

Конструкция $? в powershell существует и ее можно использовать.

`Logging SomeOperation "Some operation"` у вас не отрабатывает потому что в этом случае SomeOperation является строковым параметром, а не вызовом функции. Чтобы вызвать функцию - надо использовать скобки:

```
Logging (SomeOperation) "Some operation"
```

Но в таком случае в первый параметр попадет pipeline output функции, а не признак ее успешного выполнения, это разные вещи.

Конструкций вида `&& doIfTrue || doIfFalse` в powershell нет, вместо них можно использовать управление исключениями через try/catch:

```
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'
try {
    SomeOperation1
    SomeOperation2
    SomeOperation3
} catch {
    doIfError
}
```

Если все, что требуется от doIfError - это вывести сообщение об ошибке и остановить скрипт - то даже try/catch не нужен:

```
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'
SomeOperation1
SomeOperation2
SomeOperation3
```

PS А чтобы выводить результат выполнения только AnotherFunction - выводите его внутри, а не ловите снаружи. Логирование на то и логирование, что делается по месту, а не опосля.

Answer (score 1):

В Powershell автоматическая переменная **$?** работает примерно таким же образом, возвращая логический объект с результатом выполнения предыдущей команды (True/False).

Я поправил твой код внеся минимум изменения чтобы он мог корректно работать:

```
function Logging([int]$result, [string]$operation) {
    $Log = 'C:\LogDir\log.txt'
    $Date = Get-Date -Format "dd.MM.yyy HH:mm:ss"
    if ($result) {
        Write-Host "OK"
        Write-Host "[ OK ]    $Date $operation"
        "[ OK ]    $Date $operation" | Out-File $log -Append
    } else {
        Write-Host "ERROR"
        Write-Host "[ ERROR ]  $Date $operation failed"
        "[ ERROR ]  $Date $operation failed" | out-file $log -Append
    }
}
RunCheckState
Logging $? RunCheckState
```

Относительно значений в переменных, вы можете использовать логические операторы для определения значения. Например, вот так:

```
if ($result -eq $true) {$variable = 'DoThis'}
else {$variable = 'DoThat'}
```

Comment: Могу ошибаться, но мне кажется, что в Вашем коде $? = $True, т.к. она покажет результат выполнения операции по присвоению значения переменной $value, при этом команда SomeOperation не будет выполнена.

Comment: Именно так. Поэтому это нужно учитывать в порядке вызова функции. Вне небольшое дополнение.